# how to use viewport tag in css4 with deprecated device-width?

Tags: css, media-queries

according to this page https://drafts.csswg.org/mediaqueries-4/#mf-deprecated  device-width is deprecated in css4 (it remain in the browsers for backward compatibility) . the question is : how then we are supposed to use the viewport meta tag :

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Answer (score 1):

The "device-width" in that meta tag is completely unrelated to media queries. The deprecation of `device-width` in Media Queries 4 has no bearing on the meta tag whatsoever.